# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

say I have a table **customer** with columns **Firstname** and **lastname**
I would like to be able to write a query that selects all the customers which has
 **exact lastname** and
 the **fuzzy firstname**

The Substring is returning the values as expected when I run this just on the firstname column

**Query**

SELECT SUBSTR(firstname,1,4) from customer;

```
**output:**
ABCD
qwry
cvbn etc
```

But I am not sure how to get this work to do a match for 2 records, one of the customers having first 4 characters of firstname same as the other customer firstname.

**Example:**

Customer1:Firstname=ABCDXYZ Lastname=SSS

Customer2:Firstname=ABCD    Lastname=SSS

The expected outcome is to be able to see these 2 records in the output

Comment: what is you question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will fetch the records who has same last names and same first four characters of first name.
It uses self join. Hope the table has a primary key like id.

```
SELECT distinct c1.firstname, 
                c1.lastname, 
                c2.firstname, 
                c1.lastname
  FROM customer c1, customer c2
 WHERE c1.id <> c2.id 
   AND c1.lastname = c2.lastname
   AND substr(c1.firstname,1,4) = substr(c1.firstname,1,4)
```

Comment: Perfect! small correction substr(c1.firstname,1,4) = substr(*c2*.firstname,1,4)

Comment: oh ya thats a typo

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I understand what you are looking to do but if you know the firstName common "prefix" you can do like this :

SELECT * from Customer WHERE firstname LIKE 'ABCD%' AND lastName = 'SSS';

Comment: Basically I am trying to find matches based on fuzzy firstname(2 customers records who has match on first 4 characters of the firstname) and exact lastname.I am planning to extract a potential match report from customer table.Having said that I don't have information of customers who has the same last name and firstname fuzzy.That is what I am trying to achieve by running this query.